# Update custom settings field in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I have the code below for a simple Settings page for my custom plugin, where the user can enter their webhook URL. My issue is that when the user first enters a value and hits the submit button, everything works fine. But if they enter a new value and hit the submit button, it does not update the previously stored value.

So the question is - how do I update the value?

```
<?php
/*
This is where all the code that handles the Settings lives. e.g. where the plugin lives in the WP Admin menu, where a user adds their webhook URL etc.
*/

// Basic Security.
defined('ABSPATH') or die('Unauthorised Access');

function wppostwebhook_register_settings()
{

    register_setting('wppostwebhook_options', 'webhook_url_field_name');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'wppostwebhook_options_page');
add_action('admin_init', 'wppostwebhook_register_settings');

function wppostwebhook_options_page_html()
{
    // check user capabilities
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        return;
    }

?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1><?php echo esc_html(get_admin_page_title()); ?></h1>
        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php // output security fields for the registered setting "wppostwebhook_options"
            settings_fields('wppostwebhook_options');
            // output setting sections and their fields
            // (sections are registered for "wppostwebhook", each field is registered to a specific section) 
            ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="url_field_id">Webhook URL:</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <input type='url' class="webhook-url" id="webhook_url_field_id" name="webhook_url_field_name" size="100" placeholder="e.g. https://hook.integromat.com/j2bb812345678" value="<?php echo get_option('url_field_name'); ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <h4><?php echo 'Add the URL for the 3rd party webhook you wish to send your Post and Page data to.'; ?></h4>
            <?php do_settings_sections('wppostwebhook');
            // output save settings button
            submit_button(__('Save Webhook URL', 'textdomain'));
            ?>
        </form>
        <h3><?php echo 'This plugin outputs post & page data to the webhook you provide above, for full instrustions and examples please visit <a href="http://jonathan-wright.com/page.html">jonathan-wright.com</a>'; ?></h3>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is saving the option, but your input field is not actually displaying the option's value because you've used the wrong option **name**, which is `url_field_name` and should instead be `webhook_url_field_name` (the second parameter value for [`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/)). So the correct HTML would be:

```
<!-- I wrapped the value attribute for brevity -->
<input type='url' class="webhook-url" id="webhook_url_field_id" name="webhook_url_field_name" size="100" placeholder="e.g. https://hook.integromat.com/j2bb812345678"
    value="<?php echo get_option('webhook_url_field_name'); ?>">
```

And remember to [escape](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-output/) the value, e.g. using [`esc_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/), i.e. `echo esc_attr( get_option( 'webhook_url_field_name' ) )`.

Comment: Thank you. That's fixed it.